# How to call methods in react-visjs-timeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

Using `react-visjs-timeline`, how are methods called to the Timeline component?

Methods like:

- `timeline.fit();`
- `timeline.setItems({...});`
- `timeline.focus(id);`

I added a ref to the component, but I'm not sure what item to call methods on:

```
<Timeline
  ref={this.timelineWrapperRef}
  options={this.state.options}
  items={this.state.items}
/>
```

The [docs for `react-visjs-timeline`](https://github.com/Lighthouse-io/react-visjs-timeline/blob/master/README.md) doesn't mention how to call methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll just want to call the methods off of the `$el`.

```
this.timelineWrapperRef.current.$el.fit();
this.timelineWrapperRef.current.$el.setItems({...});
this.timelineWrapperRef.current.$el.focus(id);
```

Comment: Any full example, i tried, but not work.